# shh passphrase doesn't let me upload to github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to upload to github pages. The passphrase that I use for the repository where the code is doesn't work when I run `npm run deploy`.

Could it be that I have to add `github.io` to the config file?

In `/Users/sara/.ssh/config`

```
#user1 account
Host github.com-sara-work
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
   IdentitiesOnly yes

#user2 account
Host github.com-SaraLance
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SaraLance
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be that I have to add `github.io` to the config file?

No, you are not pushing directly to `github.io`. You are pushing to a regular GitHub repository, for which you have set a publication branch, making it eligible to be a project Github page.

As long as your passphrase is loaded by the SSH agent, `npm run` should not be blocked.

You need to make sure you are using the right SSH URL:

```
github.com-SaraLance:<user>/<repo>
# or
github.com-sara-work:<user>/<repo>
```

If npm is using a regular `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>` URL, none of your keys would be considered anyway.